# how to exclude a source package when deploying an app on JBoss within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I'm developing a java web-based application and deploying it on JBoss 5.0 within Eclipse. I have some testing packages in my project which I'd like to avoid deploying them. Is there any means by which I can tell Eclipse to exclude these testing packages from the deploying war ?

I've tried with the run configuration but didn't find the way to exclude any package.

thanks!

Comment: Just completed my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is *currently* available (except for a custom xml script which would build a custom war to deploy).

I base this on [JEE Status Meetings/2009-06-11](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JEE_Status_Meetings/2009-06-11):

> Scenario: Create a source folder in a project that has test code (which should not be deployed) - need a way to exclude folders from deployment in component file

It does look like what you want, doesn't it?

---

The same page mentions:

"we are targeting these changes for WTP 3.2": no guarantee though that it will include that exact scenario, but if it makes [WTP 3.2 (see **plan**)](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=webtools) , it should be available for eclipse Helios 3.6 (late June 2010).
An intermediate milestone might include that feature before next year though.

Comment: yeah! that's exactly what I'm looking for! ;-)

Comment: so VonC... does this mean that it's something that still has to be implemented on Eclipse ? any ideas of when it will be achieved ? thx!

Comment: perfect VonC, then we'll have to wait! I guess I can achieve this with ANT though. thanks for your help